# Is it possible to test if loading extensions is enabled in SQLite 3?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to test if [extension loading is enabled](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/enable_load_extension.html) in SQLite 3 from C interface or using SQL without actually trying to load an extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this query to check if extension loading is enabled *by default*:

```sql
SELECT sqlite_compileoption_used('ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION');
```

But this works for you only if you know that `sqlite3_enable_load_extension` is never called.

The internal `SQLITE_LoadExtension` flag is not accessible; it is read only when SQLite actually tries to load an extension.

What you could do is to try to load a known-invalid extension, such as `load_extension('/dev/null')`. If extension loading is disabled, the error message will be `not authorized` instead of something like `file too short`.

Comment: Actually I wanted precisely to test if `sqlite3_enable_load_extension` _is_ called :)